# Modifying class behavior depending on property using if() is code smell or not?

Tags: c++, oop

I have a class representing some parameter. The parameter can be number, array, enum or bitfield - this is the param type. The behavior is slightly different between these types, so they are subclasses of `paramBase` class. The parameter can be stored in RAM or be static (i.e. hardcoded in some way, currently saved in a file).

`void read()` implemented in `paramBase` and uses template method pattern to implement reading for any param type, but this works only for RAM storage.  If parameter is static then `read()` must be **completely** different (i.e. read from file).

A straightforward solution can be further subclassing like `paramArrayStatic`, `paramNumberStatic`, etc. (it will be 8 subclasses).
The difference between `paramArray` and `paramArrayStatic` is basically only in the `read()` method, so a straightforward solution will lead to code duplication.

Also I can add `if( m_storage==static )` to `read()` method and modify behavior, but this is also code smell(AFIK).

```
class paramBase
    {
    public:
        virtual paramType_t type() = 0; 
        paramStorage_t storage();

        virtual someDefaultImplementedMethod()
        {
            //default implementation
        }

        void read()
        {
            //template method pattern
            m_prop1 = blablabla;
            someDefaultImplementedMethod();
        }

    protected:
        paramStorage_t m_storage;
        int m_prop1;
        int m_prop2;
    };

    class paramArray: public paramBase
    {
    public:
        virtual paramType_t type()
        {
            return PT_ARRAY;
        }
        virtual someDefaultImplementedMethod()
        {
            //overriding default implementation of base
            //i.e. modify templated read() method behavior
        }
    protected:
        int m_additional_prop1;
        int m_additional_prop2;
    };
```

In the end, I have 4 subclasses of base and I need to modify behavior of `read()` by static/non_static modificator.

How do I solve this without code duplication and code smell? Is the condition `if( m_storage==static )` in `read()` is code smell or not?

Comment: What is "code smell" ? You mean bad style?

Comment: Check strategy design pattern. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern You have to inject to your object different read strategies.

Comment: Yes, but i need to modify read() strategy on object construction and i don't need to change it later. Strategy pattern is for runtime modification of behavior. Also strategy pattern means i need memory allocation for strategy, right? Sounds like overhead for situation when i don't need to change at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You never have to duplicate code: just only re-implement that single method `read`. If you need to use it from pointers to the base class, `virtual` does just that. If you have common code between that 8 `read` method (or just between some of them), put it in a common middle layer.

If you want to make it clear that the class might not use the method at the base level, you can make it abstract, the add a ninth subclass for the RAM case.

Having a huge switch calling 9 different `read` methods in the same class seems far worse to me.

Answer (score 0):

> Straightforward solution can be furhter subclassing like paramArrayStatic, paramNumberStatic..etc. i.e. totally it will be 8 subclasses. Difference between paramArray and paramArrayStatic is basically only in read() method, so straightforward solution will lead to code duplication.

I agree. Creating a class that overrides the behaviour in such a significant way would be in violation of the SOLID principles (specifically the LSP part).

> Also i can add if( m_storage==static ) to read() method and modify behavior, but this is also code smell(AFIK).

Who decides that this is *code smell*? It seems most expressive, and sensible to me.

Stop worrying so much about *code smells*, and start questioning the expressiveness of your options...

Comment: >"Stop worrying so much about code smells, and start questioning the expressiveness of your options..."   Good point! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SigmaN,

For your simple example I would not worry about the control coupling in the read method.  It is often better to have clear and maintainable code versus code that is strictly decoupled.

The general idea of your questions seems to be about decoupling the source of a value from the business logic for that value.  Oftentimes, a good strategy is creating an interface as an ABC and then taking an instance on the the ctor.  Here is a very simple example.

```
class ReadValue
{
   public:

   virtual int32_t readValue(std::string & value) = 0;
};

class  DatabaseReadValue::public ReadValue
{
   public:
   virtual int32_t readValue(std:string & value) override; // read from the database
}

class XMLReadValue::public ReadValue
{
   public:
   virtual int32_t readValue(std::string & value) override; // read from XML file
}

class Parameter
{
  public:

   Parameter(ReadValue & readValueObj): readValueObj_(readValueObj) {}

   int32_t read() {  return(readValueObj_.readValue(value_)); }

   ReadValue & readValueObj_;
   std::string value_;
}
```

Oftentimes, the idea will be used in a template class rather than using inheritance. The gist is the same however.

The idea is related several Design Patterns depending on the details.  Bridge, Adapter, Factory, Abstract Factory, PIMPL.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern

--Matt

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved in this way:

```
//public interface and basic functionality
class base 
{
public:
    virtual void arraySize() //part of interface
    {
        printf("base arraySize()\n");
    }
//template method read
    int read()
    {
        readImpl();
    }

protected:
    virtual void readImpl() = 0;
};

//only base functionality of array is here. no read implementation!
class array : public base
{
public:
    virtual void arraySize()
    {
        printf("array arraySize()\n");
    }

};
//implement static read for array
class stat_array : public array
{
public:
    void readImpl()
    {
        printf("stat_array read() \n");
    }

};
//implement non static read for array
class nostat_array : public array
{
public:
    void readImpl()
    {
        printf("nostat_array read() \n");
    }
};

//test
stat_array statAr;
nostat_array nonstatAr;

base *statArPtr = &statAr;
base *nonstatArPtr = &nonstatAr;

void main()
{
    statArPtr->read();
    nonstatArPtr->read();
}
```